# Generate dashboard from CSV data

Tags: php, csv

I need to produce a dashboard with the data from CSV file. Sample CSV file will be like follows.

1. 09.09.14;James;OK
2. 19.09.14;James;NOK
3. 29.09.14;Jim;NOK

The data need to be rendered like follows.

1. Name;09.09.2014;19.09.2014;29.09.2014
2. James;OK;NOK;
3. Jim;;;NOK

Can you please suggest a method to generate the dashboard from that source data file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the csv file already on the server, or do you nee to write code to handle file upload as well?

Comment: Yes it is possible in php, you could start by reading the file with fgetcsv

Comment: I've started nothing for the moment. First I would like to be sure that I'm working on the good way. I'm not fully confortable with fgetcsv solution because loops could be tricky to organize.I don't need the complet code because the method. The CSV file is already on server.

Comment: Google Charts API might be an idea. Thought you would have found that already though before posting this question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled by php array. Following is the complete working code for your requirement.

```
<pre>
<?php

$filename = 'data.csv';
$contents = file($filename);

$col[] = "Name";

foreach($contents as $line) {
    $line = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $line );
    $line_array = explode(";",$line);
    if(!in_array($line_array[0],$col)){
        $col[] = $line_array[0];
    }
    $row[$line_array[1]][$line_array[0]]=$line_array[2];
}

foreach($col as $val)
{
    echo $val . ";";
}

echo "\n";
unset($col[0]);

foreach($row as $key=>$row_val)
{
    echo $key . ";";
    foreach($col as $col_val)
    {
        if(!isset($row_val[$col_val]))
        {
            $row_val[$col_val] = "";
        }
        echo $row_val[$col_val] . ";";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

And working sample can be viewed here: http://sugunan.net/demo/csv.php

Comment: While this is reading the file, I am not sure that this is the "Dashboard" the OP was asking for - having said that the question wasn't a good fit for SO in the state it was in anyhow.

Comment: The question not clear whether he wanted output on web page or another CSV. If he wanted it on table or json that also can be done by modifying the code. The only point I try here to take the row wise date and state for person taken to column wise date and row wise person.

Comment: Thanks Guru, Thanks to you I'm close to the end. It's working but I have this error message:Name;09.09.14;19.09.14;29.09.14;
James;OK;NOK;

Notice:  Undefined index: 29.09.14 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pointage\Table2.php on line 31

;
Jim;

Notice:  Undefined index: 09.09.14 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pointage\Table2.php on line 31

;

Notice:  Undefined index: 19.09.14 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pointage\Table2.php on line 31

;NOK10.09.14; and I don't want to disable this kind of Notification

Comment: I have edit the code to fix the bug. See the answer and my link.

Comment: Now it's all good thanks for your precious help Guru.